# IllegalStateException in android.You need to use Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, xml

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>



    </style>


</resources>
```

styles.xml v21

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F44336"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    >



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

LogCar error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
                                                                               at com.tontosworld.tontosworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

The android application is working fine in android lolipop and above but in kitkat or lower version its crashing.

Please help me why it is crashing in kitkat version of android.

Log

Comment: In android manifest file check minSDKversion

Comment: Please post your logcat errors, not only the error name in the title.

Comment: Ok i have posted above @MateiaruTP

Comment: please provide the manifest entry for your MainActivity

Comment: You have to use Appcompat theme in styles.xml v21 file or may be in your java file there a activity extends Appcompat activity , check both of this may be its of some help

Comment: This is happening because you have not extended app compact theme in styles.xml v-21

Comment: I looked through your code and it appears that everywhere you are using "AppCompat" themes. Try changing the used themes to some very basic themes. Also, @yital9 's answer may be right - try removing "elevation" from the code and check whether it works after that.

Comment: Got it...Thanks @yital9...You just indirectly solved my problem...Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`elevation`  is introduced since Android API 21.

try to remove `android:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: do you want to debate, that you shouldn't use elevation on pre L versions? :)

Comment: Sorry @yital9 but i didn't vote you down...But thanks you solved my problem

Comment: Because @yital9 its not a solution